# Building a Spatial Index

Tags: geospatial, jena, fuseki, triplestore, geosparql

I want to build spatial index on my Jena Fuseki server.
I try to follow the doc here : https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/spatial-query.html

But when I restart my server I have this :

> [2018-05-24 17:05:03] Server     INFO  Apache Jena Fuseki 3.7.0
>   [2018-05-24 17:05:03] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=C:\Users\i3mainz\Desktop\JenaFusekiProject\apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0.
>   [2018-05-24 17:05:03] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=C:\Users\i3mainz\Desktop\JenaFusekiProject\apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0\run
>   [2018-05-24 17:05:03] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file://C:\Users\i3mainz\Desktop\JenaFusekiProject\apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0\run\shiro.ini
>   [2018-05-24 17:05:04] Config     INFO  Configuration file: C:\Users\i3mainz\Desktop\JenaFusekiProject\apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0\run\config.ttl
>   [2018-05-24 17:05:04] riot       WARN  [line: 32, col: 1 ] Bad IRI:  Code: 4/UNWISE_CHARACTER in PATH: The character matches no grammar rules of URIs/IRIs. These characters are permitted in RDF URI References, XML system identifiers, and XML Schema anyURIs.
>   [2018-05-24 17:05:04] Server     ERROR Exception in initialization: No rdf:type for dataset :spatial_dataset
>   [2018-05-24 17:05:04] WebAppContext WARN  Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@ca27722{/,file:///C:/Users/i3mainz/Desktop/JenaFusekiProject/apache-jena-fuseki-3.7.0/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
>   org.apache.jena.fuseki.FusekiConfigException: No rdf:type for dataset :spatial_dataset
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.getDataset(FusekiBuilder.java:119)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.buildDataServiceCustom(FusekiBuilder.java:73)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.buildDataAccessPoint(FusekiBuilder.java:65)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.servicesAndDatasets(FusekiConfig.java:121)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.processServerConfigFile(FusekiSystem.java:266)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.initServerConfiguration(FusekiSystem.java:241)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.initializeDataAccessPoints(FusekiSystem.java:207)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.serverInitialization(FusekiServerListener.java:96)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.contextInitialized(FusekiServerListener.java:53)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1514)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1476)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:273)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.start(JettyFuseki.java:137)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.runFuseki(FusekiCmd.java:367)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:351)
>           at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
>           at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
>           at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:103)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:67)
>   [2018-05-24 17:05:04] Server     INFO  Started 2018/05/24 17:05:04 CEST on port 3030

I really don't understand where i'm wrong.

Here my config:

```
    # Licensed under the terms of http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

## Fuseki Server configuration file.

@prefix :        <http://base/#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
   # Example::
   # Server-wide query timeout.   
   # 
   # Timeout - server-wide default: milliseconds.
   # Format 1: "1000" -- 1 second timeout
   # Format 2: "10000,60000" -- 10s timeout to first result, 
   #                            then 60s timeout for the rest of query.
   #
   # See javadoc for ARQ.queryTimeout for details.
   # This can also be set on a per dataset basis in the dataset assembler.
   #
   # ja:context [ ja:cxtName "arq:queryTimeout" ;  ja:cxtValue "30000" ] ;

   # Add any custom classes you want to load.
   # Must have a "public static void init()" method.
   # ja:loadClass "your.code.Class" ;   

   # End triples.
   .

<#service_spatial_tdb> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    rdfs:label                      "TDB/spatial service" ;
    fuseki:name                     "ds" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery             "query" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery             "sparql" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpdate            "update" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpload            "upload" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore    "get" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore    "data" ;
    fuseki:dataset                  :spatial_dataset ;
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: `:spatial_dataset` does not link to anything in the configuration. The file seems to be truncated.

Comment: I understand, so where must I link :spatial_dataset ?

Comment: In the file. The example in https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/spatial-query.html builds on the dataset decription higher up the page. Include RDF `:spatial_dataset rdf:type     spatial:SpatialDataset ;` and the details of setting up the dataset.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, now everything seems to work correctly but when i build the index i have this error : 
org.apache.jena.assembler.exceptions.AssemblerException: caught: Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 3, column 3.
Was expecting one of:
    <IRIref> ...
    <PNAME_NS> ...
...

The problem is that there is nothing corresponding at line 3, col 3 on my config